# log to one file from many processes with Java Logger

Tags: java, java.util.logging

Is there anyway to log messages from different processes to the same log file using Java Logger ?

Comment: That sounds like a race condition waiting to happen.  Perhaps create a separate application which owns the file and listens on a socket for messages, then have the rest of the processes send messages to that application?  Or perhaps log to a database instead of a file?  Having multiple processes fighting for control over a single file probably won't go over well.

Comment: i'm afraid i had to agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

You can [add multiple handlers to a Logger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html#addHandler(java.util.logging.Handler)). Create multiple FileHandler instances and add them all to your logger (or the root logger if you want all loggers to write to multiple files).

Comment: Sorry, I gave you the reverse answer of how to log to many files from one java process. You can create a FileHandler which points to the same file as a FileHandler in another application, but as @David pointed out, it's a race condition waiting to happen.